# Если несколько инпутов не заполнены

Tags: jquery, input

Есть блок, в нём с самого начала два инпута.

Есть кнопка, которая добавляет в блок ещё инпут, т.е. инпутов может быть несколько.

И есть ещё одна кнопка.

Вопрос, как сделать так, чтобы вторая кнопка было "заблокирована" до тех пор, пока хотя бы в двух инпутах не будет какого-либо значения.

---

HTML:

```
<div class="list opa-inputs">
   <input type="text" placeholder=".."/>
   <input type="text" placeholder=".."/>
</div>

<input type="button" id="add" value="Добавить"/>
<input type="button" id="creat" value="Вторая кнопка" disabled="disabled"/>
```

JQ:

```
$('#add').on('click', function(){
   $('.list').append('<input type="text" placeholder="..."/>');
});
```

Comment: а сами пробовали что то в виде кода написать ?

Comment: А что именно не получается?  Выложи сюда  код...

Comment: Добавил код, вот.

Comment: у вас два варианта - либо обрабатывать событие `change` инпутов где проверять заполненность полей и блокировать кнопку. Либо при нажатии кнопки проходить по инпутам и если не  заполнено, то делать выход. Так что в зависимости от необходимой логики реализуйте один из них.

Comment: Это-то понятно.. Я вот чёт догнать не могу, как реализовать :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Предполагаю что вы это имели ввиду

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var createButton = $("#create-input");
  createButton.click(function() { // по клику создаем в DOM новый инпут с типом text
    $('#wrapper').append('<input type="text" onchange="inpValue()" />');
  })
  inpValue(); // при иницилизации скрипта вызываем функцию
});


function inpValue() {
  var inputs = $("input[type=text]"); // Находим все инпуты с типом text
  var disbleButton = $("#some-btn"); // Находим кнопку которую нужно скрыть
  var data = []; // Пустой массив :))) 
  $.each(inputs, function(index) { // Проходим по всем инпутам которые есть в DOM
    if ($(inputs[index]).val().length >= 1) { // Делаем проверку, если value инпута больше одного пропускаем через проверку
      data.push($(inputs[index]).val()); // Записываем в дату value нашего инпута
    }
  });
  if (data.length >= 2) { // Проверяем, есть в нашей data больше чем 2 заполненных инупта ставим кнопке false или true если меньше
    disbleButton.prop('disabled', false);
  } else {
    disbleButton.prop('disabled', true);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="wrapper">
  <input type="text" value="1" onchange="inpValue()" />
  <input type="text" onchange="inpValue()" />
  <input type="text" onchange="inpValue()" />
</div>
<button id="create-input">Создать поле для ввода</button>
<input id="some-btn" type="button" value="Кнопка" disabled>
```

Comment: Объясните код человеку на будущие.

Comment: Огромное спасибо